# Not able to start windows update from services.msc

Tags: windows-10, services, error-correction

My Windows update  on Services.msc always stays in Disable state. I am not able to enable Windows update from Services.msc. I went to its properties and changed startup type as Manual|Automatic -> Clicked on Apply -> then it gives me option to Start. When I click on start, I am getting message "Error 1058: The service cannot be started on, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it". Service status is always stopped.

On Windows Update property tab, I went to Logon and changed log on as Local System account as well as choosed this account and tried but nothing helped. Not I am struggling to perform windows update.

Windows Version I am using:
Microsoft Windows
Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.1082)

Comment: [Add on your post the Windows version (by using the *winver* command line on Command Prompt)](https://kb.netgear.com/20246/Using-Winver-command-to-find-the-Windows-version)

Comment: Do you have some anti-malware installed on that computer? Run some good anti-malware, do a full scanning. There are some kinda malwares that *definitely disable* the Windows Update no Windows.

Comment: Did you try to enable the Windows Update with the *Administrator account*?

Comment: I have added windows version..

Comment: Still lack of the hardware setup.

Comment: hardware setup?

Comment: Sorry my bad, not necessary for your kinda issue.

Comment: [Did you try *remove all last updates* one by one whether possible? Sometimes some lastet updates cause similar issues like yours. Already ocurred a similar one on my wife's laptop and that solved the her issue.](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-uninstall-a-windows-10-update)

Answer (score -1):

1. First try windows update troubleshooting.
   This can be found at Settings/Update and Security/Troubleshoot.
2. If that doesn't fix it you can try to start it with command prompt.
   Start the command prompt.
   Then type these commands.

   net stop wuauserv

   net stop cryptsvc

   net stop bits

   net stop msiserver

   ren c:\windows\softwaredistribution *.old

   ren c:\windows\system32\catroot2 *.old

   net start msiserver

   net start bits

   net start cryptsvc

   net start wuauserv

Here all the commands startring with net are to stop and start the corresponding services and those starting with ren are to update the catalogs.
Let me know if it works as the second one works in most cases.

Comment: I am not able to start. On running "net start wuauserv" I am getting error:                  
"System error 1058 has occured.
The service can not be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it"

Comment: You can try this: Frist type %windir% in Run box and then go to softwaredistribution folder and delete the data store folder.Then try the above solution.

Comment: Did exactly.. Still getting same error...